What is the anglicization of 팻잎?
팻잎

When I want to preserve the sound of a Korean word and use English writing for 팻잎, then what do you suggest?
Below we see a photograph of an specimen of a particular species of edible salad green that our question pertains to.


This is rather question for english.stackexchange.com. Anyway the closest English spelling for [pʰɛs.ip̚] would be "pes-ip" or "pes'ip".

깻잎 is pronounced as [깬닙] - according to the current standard, its Romanization is kkaennip.
As for why the ㄴ sound is inserted, see this question: Why is 꽃잎 pronounced as 꼰잎?

It is not 팻잎. It is 깻잎. 깻잎 is the leaf of the 깻 plant. 깨 (kkae) is a very small seed. Therefore, 깻잎 literally means "leaf of the 깨 plant." Grammatically, it should be 깨잎, but for pronunciation purposes, it changes to 깨ㅅ잎, which becomes 깻잎. It is pronounced 깬닢, which sounds like "kkaenip" or "ggan-nip." Actually, ㄲ is not exactly like "k" in English; it is a tense consonant, which is why it is pronounced differently.
I searched some korean blog. it is Perilla leaf by english.
